# Can I invite a non Stack Exchange user into a private beta?

Tags: support, users, beta-phase, private-beta

Does someone have to be a Stack Exchange user in order to be invited into a private beta, such as English Language Learners?

I'm referring to the "Invite Fellow Experts" form on the right hand side of https://ell.stackexchange.com/ , between "tag subscriptions" and "recent tags".

Comment: As far as I know, to take part in private beta one have to first be Commited to the site via Area 51 while it's still in the stage of proposal. All the commiters then get email invitation to join the private beta, regardless of other accounts they might have in Stack Exchange. So from this looks like that one only need account on Area 51.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd sorry, didn't make myself clear. Added a second sentence.

Comment: Oh, wasn't aware such form exists! Well, that's a good question. In my invitation mail to a site I once commited to it says: "Q: How do I log in? A: Use the same Open ID you use for other Stack Exchange sites." From this one might understand that existing account on other site is required, however personally I think it will work just fine without any other site. Give it a try and worst case ask that person to create account somewhere but at least you'll have the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to invite someone who'd never used Stack Exchange before into a private beta. So, the answer is yes.